# How to time a matrix multiplication in C?

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I want to ask for help to measure the execution time of matrix multiplication below. I'm running the code in Windows. I've try to using [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/), but it can't measured. Where I have to put the timer?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

void main()
{
    int m1[10][10],i,j,k,m2[10][10],add[10][10],mult[10][10],r1,c1,r2,c2;
    /*double dif;
    time_t start, end;*/

    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of first matrix MAX 10\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r1,&c1);
    printf("Enter number of rows and columns of second matrix MAX 10\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&r2,&c2);
    if(r2==c1)
    {
        printf("Enter rows and columns of First matrix \n");
        printf("Row wise\n");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
                scanf("%d",&m1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("You have entered the first matrix as follows:\n");
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c1;j++)
                printf("%d\t",m1[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("Enter rows and columns of Second matrix \n");
        printf("Again row wise\n");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
                scanf("%d",&m2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("You have entered the second matrix as follows:\n");
        for(i=0;i<r2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
                printf("%d\t",m2[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        /*time (&start);*/
        printf("Now we multiply both the above matrix \n");
        printf("The result of the multiplication is as follows:\n");
        /*a11xA11+a12xA21+a13xA31 a11xA12+a12xA22+a13xA32 a11xA13+a12xA23+a13xA33*/
        for(i=0;i<r1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<c2;j++)
            {
                mult[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<r1;k++)
                {
                    mult[i][j]+=m1[i][k]*m2[k][j];
                    /*mult[0][0]=m1[0][0]*m2[0][0]+m1[0][1]*m2[1][0]+m1[0][2]*m2[2][0];*/
                }
                printf("%d\t",mult[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            /*time (&end);
            dif (difftime (end, start);
            printf("Time of execution is : %f\n",dif)*/
        }
        getch();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Matrix multiplication cannot be done");
    }
}
```

I want the measurement as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think  you'd be best off with your 'end time' code outside the loops you've currently got, immediately before the call to `getch()`.  This would give you the maximum chance of counting more than 1 second.  To get a decent measure, you probably need to repeat the whole multiplication a number of times (so that the total elapsed time is measured in 10s of seconds).  You should avoid printing in the loop, too; the printing time will likely dominate the calculation time.

The rest of your trouble is that the `time()` system call provides 1 second resolution on the timing.  You really need a timing routine with sub-second resolution such as [`gettimeofday()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) (microsecond) or [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) (nanosecond).  Note that resolution and accuracy are different.  (You could use [`clock()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html) instead, which is Standard C but normally provides much less resolution.  Historically, there was also `ftime()` and `times()` that could be used.  These gave millisecond resolution.)  There are other system calls available on Windows.  You will still want a significant repeat count to make the timing useful (1000 times, or 10,000 times, or 1,000,000 times) because it does not take long to do a 10x10 matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

the time function's precision, so if the code executes less than 1 second, you can't get correct output.
On windows, I prefer to use [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

sample

```
#include "Windows.h"
int main (void)
{
  DWORD start,end;
  start = GetTickCount();
  //do something like Sleep(1000)
  end = GetTickCount();
  printf("elapse %d milliseconds\n", end - start);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example please?

Comment: @sintakartika has sample for u

Comment: hai @RolandXu. i've try it, but when i run it, why just appear the time elapse? Necessarily, I input the matrix, then it executes and when the output matrix shown with the time elapsed...

Answer (score 0):

How about using `clock()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
 clock_t start, stop;
 double t = 0.0;

 /* Start timer */ 
 start = clock();    
 assert(start != -1);

 /* Perform calculations */

 /* Stop timer */
 stop = clock();
 t = (double) (stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
 printf("Run time: %f\n", t);

 return(0);
} /* main */
```

Comment: NEVER put code with required side effects in an `assert`! The timer won't get started in "Release" configurations, when asserts are stripped.  Instead, use two lines: `start = clock(); assert(start != -1);`.